# Symfony Form not showing correct error (pending on constellation)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, error-handling, constraints

I have an issue with the constrains-check of my form and the correct display of errors.

### describtion of problem

The form has three checkboxes and two of them are mandatory to be checked by the user (accepting Terms and Conditions stuff).

- if only one of the mandatory checkboxes (either the first or the secound) is not checked, the error is displayed correctly
- if both mandatory checkboxes are not checked, no error is displayed at all

### analysis already done

- looping through errors [link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1077/how-to-render-form-errors-in-a-list-with-twig-in-symfony-4) show that there is really no error
- if i add an additional textfield to the form, the above problem disappears (but I don't want that field).

### BookingTermsAndConditionsFormType.php

```
class BookingTermsAndConditionsFormType  extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
            ->add('checkbox1', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label'      => 'accept <a href="#" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a>.*',
                'label_html' => true,
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'switch-custom'],
                'constraints' => [
                    new IsTrue([
                        'message' => 'Accepting Terms and Conditions are mandatory.',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('checkbox2', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label'      => 'accept <a href="#" target="_blank">privacy policy</a>*',
                'label_html' => true,
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'switch-custom'],
                'constraints' => [
                    new IsTrue([
                        'message' => 'Accepting privacy policy is mandatory.',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('checkbox3', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label'      => 'I want the newsletter.',
                'label_html' => true,
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'switch-custom'],
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults([]);
    }
}
```

### _formTermsAndConditions.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(bookingTermsAndConditionsForm, {
    attr: {
        class: 'form-general',
        novalidate: 'novalidate',
        id: 'form_booking_terms_and_conditions'
    }
}) }}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-10 offset-2">
        <div>
            {{ form_row(bookingTermsAndConditionsForm.checkbox1) }}
            {{ form_row(bookingTermsAndConditionsForm.checkbox2) }}
            {{ form_row(bookingTermsAndConditionsForm.checkbox3) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



{{ form_end(bookingTermsAndConditionsForm) }}
```

### Question

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find here my workaround.
I have added an additional field and used the `HiddenType` for it. This made the form-errors work correctly. Don't ask me why...

### BookingTermsAndConditionsFormType.php

```
[...]

$builder
    ->add('dummy', HiddenType::class, [
        'label' => 'i am stupid and only needed because constrain-errors are not 
                    displayed correctly without me (e.g. in the case both mandatory 
                    checkboxes are not checked).'
    ])

[...]
```